# Java app does not work on command line is fine in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

Sorry for the very general headline and the long description to follow.  Thanks in advance for anyone who reads this and answers.

I have an app that takes a VM argument and a commandline argument.  It is a maven project.  I run it in eclipse from a Java Application run configuration. No problem.  It creates a PDF file and System.out() calls actually print to STDOUT. Logging calls print to the eclipse console.  All as expected.

When I build in maven (I'm using git bash shell on Windows 7):

```
$ mvn clean compile package
```

The jar is built with all the dependencies inside and the persistence.xml file included.  I run from the command line

```
$ java -jar target/dne-caprs-reports-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  -Dgov.ssa.dne.reportdir=C:\temp\ upcoming_changes
```

No errors.  Hooray. But... no PDF and no messages on STDOUT.   There should be some messages on STDOUT. I searched the whole file system for the PDF in case they were being output somewhere unexpected. Nothing.

I ftped the jar to a Linux box and ran it the same way (with a different reportdir obviously) and got the same result. No PDF. No STDOUT. No Logging (though I have no idea if I did the logging correctly).

So "does not work" means the app appears to run fine except no output on STDOUT and no PDF file is created.  AND no errors at all.

Main class: RunReport.java:

```
package gov.ssa.dne.app;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import gov.ssa.dne.reports.ChangeStatusReport;
import gov.ssa.dne.reports.OpenChangesReport;
import gov.ssa.dne.reports.OpenProblemReport;
import gov.ssa.dne.reports.UpcomingChangesReport;

public class RunReport {

public static void main(String[] reports) {

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dne-caprs-reports");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    if (reports[0].toString().equals("change_status")) {
        ChangeStatusReport report = new ChangeStatusReport(em, "DNE Change Status");
        System.out.println("CHANGE STATUS REPORT");
        report.generateReport();
    }


}
```

}

ChangeStatusReport.java - details removed for brevity:

```
public class ChangeStatusReport {

    private EntityManager em;
    private List<Sc6cm3rm1> changeList = new ArrayList<Sc6cm3rm1>();
    private Cell cell;
    private Table table;
    private String title;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( ChangeStatusReport.class.getName() );

    public ChangeStatusReport(EntityManager em, String title) {
        this.em = em;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void generateReport() {
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(NativeQueries.DNE_CHANGE_STATUS, Sc6cm3rm1.class);
        changeList = q.getResultList();
        createPdf();
    }

    private void createPdf() {

        String reportLocation = System.getProperty("gov.ssa.dne.reportdir");
        String report = reportLocation + "DNE_Change_Status_" + DneStyles.reportSdf.format(new Date()) + ".pdf";

        try {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(report);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4.rotate());

            // Add title
            document.add(pdfTitle);

            table = new Table(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 35, 12, 12, 3, 20 });

            document.add(table);
            document.close();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "report complete " + report);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>gov.ssa.dne.nmst</groupId>
  <artifactId>dne-caprs-reports</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dne-caprs-reports</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>gov.ssa.dne.app.RunReport</mainClass>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/persistence.xml</resource>
                  <file>src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml</file>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <LONG LIST OF DEPENDENCIES REMOVED>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

What is going on here?  I have read other answers that addressed the STDOUT issue, but those questions pertained to people trying to run the jar as the executable file without the "java -jar" part.  I'm not doing that.  Does it have to do with my maven build?  How I'm running it?  I can't think of anything else to change.

Comment: It looks like your running on a Windows machine, but perhaps using a bash prompt?  The directory argument looks peculiar, have you tried   -Dgov.ssa.dne.reportdir=C:\\temp\\upcoming_changes (escape the backslash, remove the space before upcoming)

Comment: Having no stdout is peculiar. If you replace the main with a simple 'hello world' it should  just 'work'... Also when you shade it.. Reduce your problem set to see if you can get something basic working before extending it. You definitely should have seen something.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I am using a "git bash" shell on windows. These are both great and simple suggestions.  Thank you both.  Clearly I've been looking at this fro too long!  I started with the 2nd suggestion.  Sure enough a simple java jar that does no more than print "Hello world!" to STDOUT actually did just that.   I'm going to continue from there and will post anything I find.

Comment: STDOUT problem related to brain-dead problem -- see answer.  My sysout statements occurred after the bug described below. The code never reached them and that is why they didn't print.

Answer (score 0):

My application's action depended on proper processing of the command line argument, which I was not doing.

Here is the definition of main() from RunReports.java:

```
public static void main(String[] reports)
```

Before doing anything action, we have to match a command-line argument:

```
if (reports[0].equals("change_status")) {
   // do something 
}
```

But since I had set up command line incorrectly, ie with the JVM argument AFTER the jar file, it became part of reports[0].  When I figured out how to print to STDOUT (see comment above) I was able to see what was going on. Printing my command line argument

```
reports[0]
```

yielded

```
-Dgov.ssa.dne.reportdir=C:\temp\ upcoming_changes
```

which obviously doesn't match

```
upcoming_changes
```

So nothing mysterious here.  I needed to switch some things around and tweak the path to C:\temp per @lane.maxwell and everything worked.

Final command-line statement

```
java -Dgov.ssa.dne.reportdir="C:\\temp" -jar dne-caprs.jar upcoming_changes
```

The reason why this problem did not occur in eclipse is the following:

In the Java Application run configuration, there is an Arguments tab.  In the Arguments tab there is a VM section, where I put the VM argument, and a Program Arguments section where I put the program arguments.

Since I set up the configuration correctly in eclipse, it ran correctly.